# mariadb with rails: can't install libmysqlclient-dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mariadb

I have mariadb-10.1 installed on a stock 64bit Ubuntu 15:10.

I have libmysqlclient18 succesfully installed, but I get errors when trying to install libmysqlclient-dev.

```
steve@steve:~$ dpkg -s libmysqlclient18
Package: libmysqlclient18
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libs
Installed-Size: 10
Maintainer: MariaDB Developers <maria-developers@lists.launchpad.net>
Architecture: amd64
Source: mariadb-10.1
Version: 10.1.13+maria-1~wily
Replaces: libmysqlclient18 (<< 10.1.13+maria-1~wily)
Depends: libmariadbclient18 (= 10.1.13+maria-1~wily)
Description: Virtual package to satisfy external depends
 This is an empty package that provides an updated "best" version of
 libmysqlclient18 that does not conflict with the libmariadbclient18
 package.
 .
 MariaDB is a fast, stable and true multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database
 server. SQL (Structured Query Language) is the most popular database query
 language in the world. The main goals of MariaDB are speed, robustness and
 ease of use.
Homepage: http://mariadb.org/
steve@steve:~$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1)                  but 10.1.13+maria-1~wily is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can anyone suggest how to resolve this?

Thanks :-)

Steve

Answer (score 10):

You have to install libmariadbclient-dev instead of libmysqlclient-dev when using MariaDB

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```

Comment: In order to install gearmand with mariadb as backend this library is needed

Comment: Is there a new name? I get "Unable to locate package".

Comment: Looks like the new gem name is just `libmariadb-dev`. I got this message when I tried to install: `Note, selecting 'libmariadb-dev' instead of 'libmariadbclient-dev'`

Comment: In case you are on Amazon Linux 2023, then `sudo dnf install mariadb105-devel`.

Answer (score 0):

While installing libmariadbd-dev or libmariadbclient-dev package is the easiest way, in some OS's or package managers it is not available.

For example on a mac with homebrew this is not available, I found a workaround though.

To install gem mysql2 on a mac you need mariadb-connector-c in homebrew. This package conflicts with Mariadb symlinks so you need to do run the following in the terminal:

```sh
brew unlink mariadb
brew install mariadb-connector-c
```

Inside the rails project directory, execute:
`bundle install` (or `gem install mysql2`)

```sh
brew uninstall mariadb-connector-c
brew link mariadb
```